# Why ExecutorService is not working in a stream?

Tags: java-8, executorservice

I am passing *a set of tasks* by stream, here is a simplified demo:

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool((r) -> {
        Thread thread = new Thread();
        thread.setDaemon(true); // even I removed this, it's still not working;
        return thread;
    });
    IntStream.range(0, TASK_COUNT).forEach(i -> {
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            out.println(i);
            return null;
        });
    });
```

After all the tasks **submitted**, I try to wait all of them finished using:

```
    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

But the output is none, there is nothing printed out.

Something wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

One weird **find-out** is that when using the default **DefaultThreadFactory**, it's working.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

F.Y.I Daemon threads are the the cause which I checked already. To debug, I set them on purpose.

Comment: BTW A simpler way of doing the same thing is `IntStream.range(0, TASK_COUNT).parallel().forEach(System.out::println);`  This will divide the work across all the processors on your machine using a background daemon thread pool you don't need to manage.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, thanks for the reminder. I know this method. But the **background thread pool** is not creating **daemon** threads as I wanted. Besides, passing in a simple **thread factory** is easier in java-8 now. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to pass a `Runnable` to the `Thread` constructor:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(r -> {
    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
                               ^
    thread.setDaemon(false);
    return thread;
});
```